# Maximum co-dimension of a submanifold given by finitely many holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, holomorphic-functions, several-complex-variables, complex-manifolds

Let $\Omega$ be a domain in $\mathbb{C}^{m}$ and $f_{1},\ldots,f_{k}:\Omega\mapsto\mathbb{C}$ are holomorphic functions. Assume that the common zero set, $Z(f_{1},\ldots,f_{k})$ is a submanifold in $\mathbb{C}^{m}$. Then is it true that codim$Z(f_{1},\ldots,f_{k})\leq k?$

Comment: By induction it suffices to look at $k=1$. For any polynomial $h \in \mathbb{C}[z_1,\ldots,z_m]$ non-constant in $z_m$ then $ R[z_m]/(h), R = \mathbb{C}[z_1,\ldots,z_{m-1}]$ is of dimension $m-1$. The same holds for $O(U)/(f) $ where $O(U)$ is the ring of analytic functions on $U$ a small neighborhood of $0$ and $f \in O(U), f(0) = 0$ non constant